# How to convert random uint64_t to random double in range (0, 1) using bit wise operations

Tags: c++

The best I can reach is this one (it give result between 0 ~ 0.5):

```
uint64_t const FRACTION_MASK = 0x1fffffffffffffull;
uint64_t const EXPONENT_BITS = 0x3fc0000000000000ull;
double to01(uint64_t i) {
    i = (i & FRACTION_MASK) | EXPONENT_BITS;
    return reinterpret_cast<double&>(i);
}
```

I trial and error out those magic numbers. I don't even know if this one can generate all value a double can reprenest between 0 and 0.5.

Comment: since C++11 it is easy: [std::uniform_real_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)

Comment: The bit operations are not trivial. This is because each halving of the value generates a different exponent. So you would need to scan count the index of the highest set bit, and set that as your exponent part, then discard that top set bit and rotate the remaining part in as the mantissa.
The alternative is to generate a floating point value between 1.0 and 2.0], then subtract 1.0. We used to do that in the old days and it was fractionally faster than simply putting the value in and dividing by (at the time) 65536.0

Comment: @JohnSmith But WHY? To create subtle bugs (paraphrase form your replay: any loser can do that)? For me this is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @JohnSmith Usually standard (std) is designed to be compact and fast, however, you could achieve that with bit-shifting and then xor would be in rage (0,1)

Comment: It's simple to convert a `uint64_t` to a `double` if you don't care what the transformation is. Returning `0.0` is a good start. Presumably you're after something more meaningful than that; begin by saying what it is that you want the relationship between the input value and the output value to be.

Comment: To those voting to close, how is this "too broad"? It seems pretty specific to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the way double numbers are encoded, it is hard to generate a good random number in the range (0, 1) directly, but it is easy to get one in the range [1, 2) [@GemTaylor].

```
double to_01(uint64_t i)
{
    constexpr uint64_t mask1 = 0x3FF0000000000000ULL;
    constexpr uint64_t mask2 = 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL;
    const uint64_t to_12 = (i | mask1) & mask2;
    double d;
    memcpy(&d, &to_12, 8);
    return d - 1;
}
```

Note that not all bits of `i` are used to generate the result. Also note that this function works for 64-bit IEEE-754 floating-point numbers only [@geza].

Comment: Yes, you should probably mask the input to 50 bits to ensure you keep the same quality of representation for high values and low values. On the other hand, the internal 80-bit representation can keep the resolution across the range.

Comment: @GemTaylor, could you please explain masking to 50 bits? Do you suggest to replace `mask2` with `0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFCULL`? Why is it important?

Comment: So I was suggesting that you clear the bottom 14 bits of the input random value, so that when converted to a double, the values above 0.5 are held at the same quality as the values below 10^-4. But to be honest, I don't think it matters, as they will be truncated anyway when converted to the range (1.0-2.0] with 50-odd bits precision, and work the same at 63 bits if you did the same with long doubles in 80-bit mode. When they are then subtracted to the range (0.0-1.0] they will all keep that resolution, so you should get the same distribution, in fact.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather and judging only from the question you want to map bits of `uint_64` to bits of `double` such that your `double` are between [0, 1]

double (64 bits) representation is

-1S × (1.0 + 0.M) × 2E-bias (bias being 1023)

A bit for sign S, 52 bits for matissa and 11 bits for exponent.

First `double` are signed so the sign bit cannot be mapped since you want `double` >0.0. 
Second we cannot exceed E-bias >1022 otherwise we will get over 1.0 value `double`.

therefore the mask for mapping uint_64 to double between [0, 1] is

0 01111111110 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
in hexadecimal 0x3FEFFFFFFFFFFFFFull

therefore the code

```
uint64_t const MASK = 0x3FEFFFFFFFFFFFFFull;
double to01(uint64_t i) {
    i = (i & MASK);
    return reinterpret_cast<double&>(i);
}
```

should do the trick. And with this method you have used 61 bits out of 64 bits of your uint_64.

But be warned : if your `uint_64` generator is uniform over [0, uint64_t_max] the generator obtained using `to01` will not be uniform over [0,1] !

Comment: It will **very** non-uniform: `3.65484e-229`, `1.42602e-116`, `4.34558e-152`, `1.61803e-107`, ... You'd better not touch the exponent part of a double.

Comment: However it answers the question. Does it not ? If he wants it to be uniform he should reformulate and be prepared to use only 52 bits and not 61 out of 64.

Comment: It does. We don't know the use case OP has in mind, but I can hardly imagine one where such a highly non-uniform distribution would be OK.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use
I shift by 12 to get 52 bits
I or with 1 so that I only get odd values this avoids returning 0
Then subtract 1.0 on return

If you're source of integers is uniformly distributed
Your results will be uniformly distributed

```
double convert_uint64_to_double(uint64_t value)
{
    uint64_t u64 = 0x3FF0000000000000ULL | ((value >> 12) | 1) ;
    return *(double*)&u64 - 1.0;
}

double convert_uint32_to_double(uint32_t value)
{
    uint64_t u64 = 0x3FF0000000000000ULL | (((uint64_t(value) << 1) | 1) << 19);
    return *(double*)&u64 - 1.0;
}
```